# How can I access a maven repository from a vultr server?

Tags: maven, cloud

My cloud server on vultr seems to be blocked by Maven so I cannot install some software.

For example,

```
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.4.20/byte-buddy-1.4.20.pom
```

results in `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden`. However, I can run this fine on my local computer, so it seems that my cloud server's IP is blocked. Is there any good solution to get around this?

The server is using IPV6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem with you when using VPS in `Tokyo`. So I opened a ticket in vultr, but the supporter said "This is something which is being blocked on the repository's end, not on our end. We have no control over it." I recommend switching to a VPS in `Los Angeles`, that is working for me

Comment: Yes, it seems to only be a problem with Tokyo, but not all nodes on Tokyo :/